Calculating pH for Polyprotic Acids and Buffers
I’m trying to understand how to calculate pH for polyprotic acids in different scenarios, especially in relation to buffers, and I have a couple of questions:
When
pH≫pKa or pH≪pKa, should I calculate the pH using the  expression or the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation? How do I determine when the buffer effect is no longer significant?
When
pH is between two pKa values (e.g., pKa1 and pKa 2 ), how do I calculate the pH and the concentrations of all species? Should I use Henderson-Hasselbalch for the dominant pair, or do I need to account for all equilibria simultaneously?

Lot of your questions will be answered if you add to your search keywords "site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org".
